# Text in Jetpack Compose only wraps if it's above a certain length, otherwise it ellipsizes

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a card where the text takes up three lines worth of space, regardless of its length, and the book image matches the height of that space.  In the image below, the bottom Preview is correct.

My problem is, despite setting `minLines = 3` and `maxLines = 3` on the post text, when the view is wide (or the text is only just over three lines), it overflows at two lines instead of three.  But if I shrink the width of the view (or make the text slightly longer), it overflows correctly.  It's almost as if the point at which the text overflows is farther to the right than the bounds of the text box, and I can't figure out why.

If the text is significantly longer than two lines, it wraps to three correctly, but if it's only just over two lines, it ellipsizes at two lines rather than wrapping to three.

[image: Previews]

(pseudo-code) Composable structure:

```
Card(modifier) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    AsyncImage() // user profile image
                    Column(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .heightIn(min = 48.dp)
                            .padding(start = 8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text() // user display name
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                        Text() // timestamp
                    }
                }
                
                Text(
                    // post text goes here
                    minLines = 3,
                    maxLines = 3,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 12.dp)
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp)
            
            AsyncImage(
                // image goes here
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                      .weight(1f, false)
                      .fillMaxHeight()
            )
        }
        SpacerDp(12.dp)
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            ReactionButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tested your code on my mac. it's working fine it shows three line when text exceeds the limit.